# I am using celltree widget of GWT . How do i remove its ugly selection border?

Tags: gwt, cell, custom-cell

Whenever I select any item in Cell tree I get this ugly bodrer!
[image]
Now I have changed the css of deafult cell tree as follows

```
.cellTreeSelectedItem {

        height: auto;
        overflow: auto;
        border:none !important;
}
```

But nothing really works .
Any suggestion would be of great help.

P.S. I knwo the CSS of this widget sucks but I am working at it.

Comment: Try with `border:0 !important;`

Answer (score 0):

A CellTree renders as few nested `div` elements and a table. You need to examine the elements inside the item to see which one gives it a border. Then you'll need to remove it. Something like:

```
.cellTreeSelectedItem tr {
    border:none !important;
}
```

Note that the [GWT Showcase](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTree) does not show any border around the selected item in Chrome or Firefox, so it actually maybe a default browser behavior for a focused element.

Comment: Yes but it uses image for the selection. The blue thing that highlights the selected item is an image and I have successfully removed it however another problem persists now and that is the border of a selected item.

Comment: As I said, there is no border in Chrome or Firefox on a CellTree, unless you added it somehow.